# change share by email chosen headline in google chrome mobile browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, sharing

I would like to change the headline the google chrome mobile browser chooses when sharing one of my pages via E-Mail.

At the moment it takes the last path segment out of the  tag.

Is there a way to mark certain HTML or a `<meta>` tag to explicitly tell what the browser should take as a headline value?

Comment: Do you have a `<title>` tag?

Comment: sorry I misinterpreted the behaviour. My title tag and the path segment are the same so I thought it takes the segment. Still the question is how to override that behaviour

Comment: Change the `<title>` tag.

Comment: can not. the title has a specific functionality in my case. Any other way to define the email headline?